# How do I copy to the clipboard using an HTML button, with variable values?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm creating a search site for video content. In the results, I'd like to have a button that will copy to the clipboard the Video name and Video URL that I have in the database.
I've found a JS function that will copy set text("Copied text" in the code below). I need the function to copy a variable(from an array), which will change, depending what someone is searching for.

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Video Name & URL</button>`

```
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = "Copied text";
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.value = copyText;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(input)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: Where does this array come from? You have used tag `php`, could you please highlight how you are expecting the JS to know which values to pick up? e.g. is this a 1 option per page, or perhaps different videos will be listed with their own buttons? etc. If you explain your desired outcome we can try help you out

Comment: To be more clear, the search will often bring up more than 1 answer. i.e. if searching for "jazz", there could be 20 videos that come up in a table. i.e  echo " <td>".$row["VideoName"]."</td>, etc.  I can create a concatenated variable with the 2 var - Video Name & Video URL. Just trying to figure where it goes in the function to make it all work. Thx

Answer (score -1):

```js
const handleCopy = (copyText) => {
      const textToCopy = copyText;

      if (navigator.clipboard) {
        navigator.clipboard
          .writeText(textToCopy)
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error copying to clipboard using Clipboard API:", error);
            fallbackCopyToClipboard(textToCopy);
          });
      } else {
        fallbackCopyToClipboard(textToCopy);
      }
    };

    const fallbackCopyToClipboard = (textToCopy) => {
      const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
      textarea.value = textToCopy;
      textarea.style.position = "fixed";
      document.body.appendChild(textarea);

      textarea.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");

      document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    };

    // Add event listeners to the buttons
    document.getElementById("copyButton1").addEventListener("click", () => {
      handleCopy('Text 1');
    });

    document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", () => {
      handleCopy('Text 2');
    });

    document.getElementById("copyButton3").addEventListener("click", () => {
      handleCopy('Text 3');
    });
```

```html
<button id="copyButton1">Copy Text 1</button>
  <button id="copyButton2">Copy Text 2</button>
  <button id="copyButton3">Copy Text 3</button>
```

Comment: Please explain how this solve the question. Code-only answers aren't good answers